# How to dynamically add a route to a scoped resource in Rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mixins, rails-routing

right now I am trying to generalize some of my code. So far it went well, I wrote a few mixins which I can dynamically add to Controllers or Models in order to get things done while obeying DRY.

But with my "Searchform-Helper" I hit a corner in which, right now, I am a bit clueless.

I have a mixin 'SearchIndexController' which adds the methods needed to search for data within a searchindex-table.

After including the mixin I can initialize search-actions within the according controller calling this method:

```
def init_searchaction(object, name=nil)
  singular = object.to_s.classify
  plural   = singular.pluralize
  name = "search_#{singular}".to_sym if name.nil?

  unless self.respond_to?(name)
    define_method(name) do
      # init
      success=false

      #TODO 
      # >>> DRAW NEW ROUTE TO THIS ACTION <<<

      # evaluate searchform input for Searchindex-Call
      needle = params[:query]

      success, x, notice = execute_search("#{singular}", needle)
      # send selected/filtered data to page
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js {
          render :update do |page|
            page.call "sidx_updateSearchResultContentAtIdTag", "##{plural.downcase} tbody", "#{render x}" if success
            page.call "sidx_updateNotice", success, "#{notice}"
            page.call "sidx_stopSpinner"
          end
        }
      end
    end
  else
    logger.warn("#{__FILE__}:#{__LINE__}:#{self.to_s}: search-action for '#{self.class.name}' can not be created, it already exists!")
  end
end
```

So lets say I have a User-Controller. Within the Userform I have the need to search for several objects. Lets assume I want to be able to search for users, departments and clients... with my mixin I'd just have to initialize the searchactions like this:

```
init_searchaction :user
init_searchaction :department
init_searchaction :client, :find_clients
```

these would create actions within the including controller that are called

```
search_user
search_department
find_clients
```

The only thing missing is a way to get a route for them. I don't want to have to define the route upfront. I just want to 'init_searchaction' and have the mixin create the necessary route.

So... would it be possible to add the route to the accoring search-action from withing the mixins init_searchaction method dynamically? I think the necessary code would be placed at the #TODO mark in the code example above. But I still haven't found out how to do it... I mean, actually I would be surprised if it would not be possible.

Would anyone have an idea as how to do this? Thanks in advance for any idea that leads to the solution!

Answer (score 1):

You can add work around standart dynamic route

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
```

change it to your goals and enjoy :)

Comment: hmm .. for simple cases, that would do the trick... but well let me edit my question to make my problem more transparent...

Comment: The best solution here is to make it simplier. I believe that you can simplify 70% of your logic here :)

Comment: and second advide: wrap your search logic into simple and REST controller and pass all search request to this controller - this is true Rails Way

Comment: Simpler: i am sure its possible... Search with a REST SearchController: yes again, I do agree, but right now my users have different access-levels which is controlled based on controllers. This way if a user is allowed to use a specific controller, he can use the according search_actions and the allow-access-check-logic needs only to be called once to see if he can access the e. g. 'UserController' ... if I made a SearchController, would not I have to create the whole allow-access-check-logic within that again?